# removing polymer element, file upload progressively adds more files on upload upon instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer, web-component

I have a polymer element that loads dynamically with the constructor value that is load from api in jade. example:

```
ink(rel="import", href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html")
link(rel="import", href="/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html")

polymer-element(name='my-element', constructor='MyElement')
  template
     a(id='send', on-click='{{fileUpload}}')
     form(id='filePost', action='', method='POST', accept-charset='utf-8', enctype='multipart/form-data')
        input(id='fileinput', name='file', type='file')
  script.
    Polymer({
       ready: function(){
         //do something
       },
       launch:function(){
        // prepare polymer element
       },
       fileUpload:function(){
          // create XHR request and post file and on complete event exit to home view
       },
       exitUploader:function(){
          history.pushState(null, null, '/home');
          this.fire('goUrl');
          this.remove();
       },
    });
```

ok so this works fine, on its own... although I have a basic app router that calls the file upload and navigation to the site. that goes something like this:

```
link(rel='import', href='/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html')
link(rel='import', href='/polymer/my-element') //api that returns jade to rendered html

polymer-element(name='router', attributes='attributes')
template
   div(class='container', id='appView')
script.
   (function(){
var routerView = document.querySelector('router')  
   //listen for 'navigate event' and render view
   addEventListener('goUrl',function(e){
      routerView.navigation(e);
   });
   Polymer({
      ready:function(){
        //do something
      },
      launch:function(){
        // prepare polymer element
      },
      navigation: function(){
        var self = this;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.location = window.location.pathname;
        switch(true){
           case(self.location == '/maker'):
              var maker = new MyElement();
              maker.launch();
              this.$.appView.firstChild.remove();
              this.$.appView.appendChild(maker);
           break;
           case(self.location == '/anotherlocation'):
              var anyOtherElement = newPolymerElement();
              this.$.appView.firstChild.remove();
              this.$.appView.appendChild(anyOtherElement);
           break;

        }
      },
   });
   })();
```

ok, so this works as well, my problem begins when i remove and re-render a new 'my-element' instance. when i upload such form it uploads an array of files pertinent to the history of files uploaded in previous visits. I was sure it had to do with removing the element properly from the dom on polymer, tried resetting the form on each time viewed the element. no dice. I need help! hahaha

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is here:

```
var routerView = document.querySelector('router')  
   //listen for 'navigate event' and render view
   addEventListener('goUrl',function(e){
      routerView.navigation(e);
   });
```

You're adding a listener outside of the lifecycle hooks, and not removing the listener when the element is removed from the DOM. It still fires the callback even though the element is outside of the DOM.

The issue should be solved if you clean up your view properly

```
Polymer({
    ready: function(){
        // add listeners
        window.addEventListener('goUrl', this.navigation);
    },
    detached: function(){
        // remove listeners
        window.removeEventListener('goUrl', this.navigation);
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to be the case, since routerView is a parent element for 'my-element', and he is never actually removed from the dom. I've tried your approach, and I think even though you're right on the whole not cleaning up the view properly, that's exactly what im trying to find... how to properly clean them up. Calling locally this.remove() doesnt do it, and they dont have any event listeners on their scope. I wil try it again in case I missed something and let you know *thumbs up* and thanks